# Can I use a For i loop to create multiple rotated buttons in Kivy .kv?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I want to display 24 buttons in the lower part of my GUI.

These should not be horizontal, but vertical.

Therefore I have already rotated one button by 90 degrees.

However, I don't know how / if I can create 24 buttons in .kv,

and how I can position them side by side.

Unfortunately I have big problems with the positioning,

since, as you can see in the picture, the TextInput is not quite on the same level as the label on the left. Does anyone know anything about this?
[image]

```
my .kc code:
<Gui>:
    GridLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 5
        row_force_default: True
        spacing: 1, 1
        padding: 100, 100
        Label:
            text: "Status"
            valign: 'center'
            halign: 'right'
            font_size: '48sp'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 100, 120
            padding: 100, 120
            Label:
                text: "Mitarbeiternummer"
                valign: 'center'
                halign: 'right'
                font_size: '48sp'
            TextInput:
                size_hint_y: None
                id: newchar
                text: '---'
                multiline: False
                focus: True
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}
                height: 50
                width: 150
                font_size: '30sp'
            ....
            Label:
                text: "Status"
                valign: 'center'
                halign: 'right'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 10
                row_force_default: True
                spacing: 100, 120
                padding: 100, 40
                FloatLayout:
                    ScatterLayout:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 190, 40
                        pos_hint: {"x":-0.1, "y": 0}
                        rotation: 90
                        do_rotation: False
                        do_scale: False
                        do_translation: False

                        Button:
                            text: 'Mitarbeiter x'
                            font_size: '30sp'
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You can use python (and its looping) to create a `kv` string that describes your `Buttons`, then use `Builder.load_string()` to load the created string.